# Heroku - Fatal error when pushing to a git repository

Tags: windows, git, heroku, push

I use Git Bash to push my files to a git repository. It was fine when I did this:

```
heroku login
git add .
```

but I tried this:

```
`git push heroku master
```

the following error came up:

```
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have correct access rights 
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried the following commands but they didn't work:

```
heroku keys:clear
heroku keys:add
```

I am new to Git and Heroku, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the command `git remote -v` output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't created a Heroku application yet.

You need to run the `heroku create` command, which will create a Heroku application, and add a git remote called `heroku` that points to your newly created application. After that `git push heroku master` should work fine.

Comment: what if you're not creating a new application.  I tried adding a remote to my existing repo that I cloned down (I did not clone it down with heroku clone): heroku git:remote -a cars-staging...and no luck still.  Still says it can't find the repo

Comment: Heroku create would great a new app for you. All you have to do is ignore the old application.

Comment: heroku is simplified much now