# Getting fatal errors when trying to deploy on Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I have created a new heroku app and then deployed it just once but after a few days when I am trying to deploy again to that existing Heroku app using the following command but getting some fatal errors
`git push heroku main`

getting the following errors..
`fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`
`fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

`Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

I have also tried the following commands but not working
`git push heroku master`

**Note:** I have found an answer to an old listed question where given a solution to create a new Heroku app and then deploy but my question is why my existing app is not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133143/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+fatal%3A+%22heroku+does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository%22

Comment: You likely didn't need to create a new app. Your `heroku` remote may just have been misconfigured. But if you've overwritten the configuration for that remote there's no way to confirm now.