# Updating Heroku App from different device?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm building my Express.js server app from different devices. I use the same git branch from both my PC and Laptop. And I successfully deploy this from my laptop. But the problem arises when I try to update some code and try to push from my PC using the command: `$ git push heroku main`.

It returns the following result:

```
$ git push heroku main
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there anything I am missing? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: probable duplicate: [Heroku - Fatal error when pushing to a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19107881/1256452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to add heroku as a git remote with the heroku cli?
`heroku git:remote -a example-app`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#for-an-existing-app

Comment: Thank you for your answere. This was the case.